# Como fazer o select virar obrigatório, usando o multiselect?

Tags: jquery-ui-multiselect

Como posso fazer um select que usa o plugin multiselect virar obrigatório?

Estou tentando dessa forma, mas ainda não consegui achar uma solução

```
$(".multiselect").multiselect({
  required: "required";
})
```

Se possível gostaria que me explicassem também porque o código acima não funciona. Grato :)

Comment: Você está utilizando algum plugin de validação?

Comment: Eu tentei usar o jquery validate, mas não consegui